# SQL Server regex pattern to check the last byte of string

Tags: sql-server

I have table `table_1` which has a column `column_1`, I need to make sure `column_1` contains only 'VAL1' or 'VAL2'...'VAL9' ie; the last byte should contain only 1-9

I'm trying to implement this query

```
select * 
from table_1
where column_1 like 'VAL[0-9]%'
```

I'm worried this will check will pass `VAL0NEW` as well.. How do I implement a check to make sure [0-9] is the last byte and there are no more characters after that?

Answer (score 3):

remove the last %

```
select * from table_1 where column_1 like 'VAL[0-9]'
```